# cases in mysql not working

Tags: mysql, database

```
UPDATE a_timeblock SET timeblock_due_date=DATE(timeblock_next_update), 
CASE timeblock_recurrence_unit
 WHEN day THEN
       DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL timeblock_recurrence_time  day ) 
 WHEN month THEN
       DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL timeblock_recurrence_time  month) 
  END

 WHERE timeblock_recurrence=1 AND timeblock_complete=0 AND timeblock_next_update=    
 FROM_UNIXTIME(1337662800)
```

The above query is wrong. i want to do something like above. How do i do it if possible.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near 
'CASE timeblock_recurrence_unit WHEN 'day' THEN DATE_ADD(NOW(),IN' at line 2
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: And what exactly is wrong, what is the error message, etc. We do not have a DB populated with your tables and setting, help us focus on the problem please.

Comment: timeblock_recurrence_unit contain day month some time years. i just want to use date_add() to compute the next date for update.

Answer (score 1):

You have no target column for your second value.

```
UPDATE a_timeblock
SET timeblock_due_date = DATE(timeblock_next_update), 
    column_name?       = CASE ... END
WHERE ...
```

Comment: timeblock_next_update = DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL timeblock_recurrence_time  day )

Comment: @user1410812: Err... is that a question or a correction to my answer or what? It's not clear to me what you are trying to say / ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use quotes around your values in the case and simply SET `timeblock_due_date`:

```
...
SET timeblock_due_date =
CASE timeblock_recurrence_unit
  WHEN 'day' THEN
       DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL timeblock_recurrence_time  day ) 
  WHEN 'month' THEN
       DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL timeblock_recurrence_time  month) 
END
...
```

This assumes `timeblock_recurrence_unit` is a `VARCHAR` type (which it would need to be)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
UPDATE a_timeblock SET timeblock_due_date=
CASE timeblock_recurrence_unit
 WHEN 'day' THEN
       DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL timeblock_recurrence_time  day ) 
 WHEN 'month' THEN
       DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL timeblock_recurrence_time  month) 
  END

 WHERE timeblock_recurrence=1 AND timeblock_complete=0 AND timeblock_next_update=    
 FROM_UNIXTIME(1337662800)
```